# setInterval behaving sporadically in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

I am trying to cast some data to state on an interval, I am trying to make a graph that updates every x seconds.

```
fuction func() {
    console.log('Hello, world!')
}

setInterval(func, 5000)
```

Instead of responding every 5 seconds as expected I get two responses every 10 seconds, this problem gets far worse when i try and cast to state as I actually want to.

Here is the response from my API call, I all I am trying to do is cast it to state and log the result.

```
{
  "_id": "60d5e8a81a68bb7b14d9f3b0",
  "symbol": "LTC",
  "perc": "3.55",
  "createdAt": "2021-06-25T14:31:04.677Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-06-25T14:31:04.677Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

When I use the below code, instead of a double result in double the time, it goes absolutes haywire.

```
let [ltcArb, setLtcArb] = useState([]);

    const fetchLtcArbHandler = () => {
        fetch("/arb/ltc")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => setLtcArb((prev) => [{ perc: json.perc, time: json.createdAt },...prev,]))
            .then(console.log(ltcArb));
    };

    function poes() {
        console.log("poes");
    }

    setInterval(fetchLtcArbHandler, 5000);
```

I have been knocking my head at this for hours and quite honestly lost some sleep last night. Any and all help will be appreciated, take it easy on me please I am still very very new here. Thanks

Comment: You can use the browser "Network" developer tool to check when the HTTP requests occur. From the code you posted, it's pretty much impossible to tell what's going on. The `setInterval()` method is not guaranteed to be absolutely accurate, but it should be pretty close to 5 seconds in your case.

Comment: Is the `setInterval` in the body of a function component? If so, it will create a new interval each render which will cause an infinitely increasing amount of function calls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Setup a setInterval Timer Properly in a React Functional Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333897/how-to-setup-a-setinterval-timer-properly-in-a-react-functional-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using a functional component which is actually the **render function** of the component.

It's being executed every time you re-render the component, thus every time you change the state.

What you need is encapsulate it in a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with an empty dependency array like this:

```
useEffect(() => setInterval(fetchLtcArbHandler, 5000), []);
```

Also, you need to return a cleanup function, otherwise the requests will run indefinitely even when the component is unmounted, while also causing a memory leak because of the potential closure context references:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(fetchLtcArbHandler, 5000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Strangely enought when I don't use the cleanup function it behaves almost as expected but when I do use it then it starts to update in double the time again. 

at the moment when I run fetchLtcArbHandler onClick of a button then it adds to the state but not when the function gets called by the useEffect and setInterval, any ideas? thansk

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the full code, my guess is that you wrote `onClick={fetchLtcArbHandler()}` instead of `onClick={() => fetchLtcArbHandler()}`